# DISTINCT запрос mysql

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица. В ней поля :

`id`, `main_code`, `sub_code`, `operator`

примерные данные

```
1 | 962 | 289 | beeline
2 | 962 | 290 | beeline
3 | 962 | 291 | beeline
4 | 924 | 222 | megafon
5 | 924 | 223 | megafon
```

мне нужно получить примерно такой список

```
962 - beeline
924 - megafon
```

т.е все уникальные `main_code`

Знаю делается через `DISTINCT`, но не получается.

Вот пример:

```
SELECT DISTINCT main_code,operator FROM codes  ORDER BY main_code ASC
```

но он выбирает уникальные группы.. т.е  маин_код + оператор
А мне надо просто уникальный код  и вывести для него оператора

Comment: Что значит "вывести для него"? Куда вывести? Если для одного кода возможны два оператора (не верю), то что надо выводить? В противном случае яснее надо показать, что должно получаться.

     962 - beeline 924 - megafon

как раз при таком запросе и получается

Answer (score 1):

Ну так не выбирайте operator, раз он вам не нужен: ))

```
SELECT DISTINCT(main_code),operator FROM codes ORDER BY main_code ASC
```

Comment: Он нужен) Его нужно вывести после кода. Можно конечно двумя запросами, но лучше то 1)

Comment: Ну тогда вы сами сначала разберитесь, что вам нужно. Один запрос - один результат запроса, никак иначе быть не может. А вы хотите чтоб от одного запроса было два результата...


Хотите один запрос, так тяните тогда им все необходимые данные, а потом уже в коде обрабатывайте только нужные.

Обновил ответ.

Comment: Вы наверно первый раз с mysql работаете. Я прекрасно описал что мне нужно. Вытащить в одном запросе много данных (Даже с разных таблиц!!! не фантастика, join и т.д) А вытащить данные с одой таблички, только выбрав уникальные значения одного поля довольно просто. Просто надо правильно сгрупировать, что у меня не получается.

Поэтому я и написал тут.

SELECT DISTINCT main_code,operator FROM codes GROUP BY main_code ORDER BY main_code ASC

Немного не то. Уже устал эксперементировать

Comment: Ну раз вы "не первый раз с mysql работаете", то Бог в помощь! Но для начало к учебнику по русскому языку не мешало бы обратиться в раздел "знаки препинания", чтоб не писать набор слов и выражать свои желания правильно!

Answer (score 1):

А что у разных операторов может быть один maincode?

```
SELECT main_code, MIN(operator) FROM codes GROUP BY main_code ORDER BY main_code
```

ЗЫ Как вариант, не `MIN` использовать, а `GROUP_CONCAT` или `MAX`...

Answer (score 1):

Тогда так:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.main_code, t2.operator FROM codes as t1 left JOIN 
(select  main_code, operator from codes) as t2
ON t1.main_code =t2.main_code
```

Comment: Результат будет тот же - все пары main_code + operator.

Comment: Не совсем - будут все main_code и соответствуюшие им первые попавшие operator

Comment: Ужас. Сначала сделать декартово произведение для каждого main_code, а затем DISTINCT'ом убрать повторения. А если ещё один подзапрос добавить? Или два?